# Do I need custom encryption algorithms in my node js server?

Tags: node.js, cryptography, cryptojs

I am developing a Node JS server for an application which will serve on an institutional scale. Few thousand calls could be performed by clients in a few seconds.

This server accepts a JWT and shares sensitive information,
If the provided token is expired, the server sends an encrypted file and another token .

Now, should I develop by own cryptography algorithms/functions for my application or just proceed with available packages like bcrypt or crypto?

My existing system just uses the crypto module and I heard creating custom encryption functions could be reusable and useful if set to a database schema (i seriously dont know what the last one means)

Comment: Unless you're a bona fide cryptography expert, writing your own encryption algorithms is almost never a good idea. Question is opinion-based and will eventually be closed as off-topic though.

Comment: you should never "roll your own crypto", but that does not seem to be what's happening here. You're asking whether there is an out-of-the-box solution to your use-case, or if you will need to write custom code. The answer is B, with a heavy does of A